# MS-Access query to collect comma-separated results in another column

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

If I have a table called **Activities**:

[image: ActivitiesTable]

..and another table called **Tutors**:

[image: TutorsTable]

If I were to do a simple `LEFT JOIN` for the tutor names on their LearnerId / InstanceId records in the activities table I would get a result like this:

[image: QueryResult]

(Sql for the above result):

```sql
SELECT Activities.LearnerId, Activities.InstanceId, 
Activities.LastName, Activities.FirstName, Activities.Activity, 
Tutors.TutorLastName, Tutors.TutorFirstName
FROM Activities 
LEFT JOIN Tutors ON (Activities.InstanceId = Tutors.InstanceId) 
AND (Activities.LearnerId = Tutors.LearnerId);
```

I would prefer that the number of records in the **Activities** table is maintained (i.e. the query results in 4 records rather 7).

I would also like every tutor matched to a LearnerId / InstanceId record to be collected in another column called **Tutors(s)**, where the names of the related tutors are all listed in one field with commas separating each tutor. In other words, a results that looks like this:

[image: PrefQueryResult]

...is it possible to do this just in SQL, or can this only be achieved in VBA?

Comment: First read this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5517233/ms-access-query-concatenating-rows-through-a-query

And then read this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5174362/microsoft-access-condense-multiple-lines-in-a-table/5174843#5174843

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is quite possible to get what you want using a VBA Function.

Allen Browne has well documented code for this operation. It is called "Concatenate Vales from Related records". Have a browse through. http://allenbrowne.com/func-concat.html

Comment: You're welcome, post back if you get into troubles. :)