# MS ACCESS Group Query

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

This one really has me scratching my head.  It's sort of like a GROUP_CONCAT, but different.  I'm pretty sure there is no way to do this with SQL only.  I have a query that does a flip-table on a normalized table.  The result looks like this:

```
|_Category_|_FieldA_|_FieldB_|_FieldC_|
|----------|--------|--------|--------|
|   CAT1   |    A   |        |        | 
|----------|--------|--------|--------|
|   CAT1   |        |    B   |        | 
|----------|--------|--------|--------|
|   CAT1   |        |        |    C   | 
|----------|--------|--------|--------|
|   CAT1   |   D    |        |        | 
|----------|--------|--------|--------|
|   CAT1   |        |        |    E   |   
|----------|--------|--------|--------|
|   CAT1   |    F   |        |        | 
|----------|--------|--------|--------|
```

My challenge is to compress it into as few rows as possible, but only have one value per cell.

```
|_Category_|_FieldA_|_FieldB_|_FieldC_|
|----------|--------|--------|--------|
|   CAT1   |    A   |    B   |    C   | 
|----------|--------|--------|--------|
|   CAT1   |    D   |        |    E   | 
|----------|--------|--------|--------|
|   CAT1   |    F   |        |        | 
|----------|--------|--------|--------|
```

Any Ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Mark

Comment: "Compress"... based on what condition?

Comment: If you would like to normalize it, i'd suggest to redesign it. Have you any chance to do that?

Comment: The link below should give you your answer:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5517233/ms-access-query-concatenating-rows-through-a-query

Comment: The database is normalized. The actual table contains a field for the Category, a field that designates a division, and a third field for the value.  When it's flipped, each division becomes a column.  Each row in the query caries a value for a division.  The client wants the data "compressed" - the first item for division 1, the first item for division 2, and the first item for division 3 appear on the first fow for that category.  You can see this pattern in the example of the results I need.

Comment: The example provided is the equivelant of the Group_Concat function in MySQL.  It's close, but not quite what I need.  Group_Concat creates a delimited list and only one row for the grouping field.  What I need is a row for each item in the column that has the most items in the category, in the sample it's FieldA

Comment: You could use it for each column, create a table for each of your 3 columns, then do a simple join query with the new tables, no?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As i mentioned in my comment to the question, normalized table should look like:

```
|_Category_|_F_Name_|_F_Val__|
|----------|--------|--------|
|   CAT1   | FieldA |    A   |
|----------|--------|--------|
|   CAT1   | FieldB |    B   |
|----------|--------|--------|
|   CAT1   | FieldC |    C   |
|----------|--------|--------|
|   CAT1   | FieldB |    D   |
|----------|--------|--------|
|   CAT1   | FieldC |    E   |
|----------|--------|--------|
|   CAT1   | FieldA |    F   |
|----------|--------|--------|
```

How to achieve that?

```
SELECT A.Category, "FieldA" AS FieldName, A.FieldA AS FieldValue
FROM TableA AS A
WHERE NOT A.FieldA IS NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT A.Category, "FieldB", A.FieldB
FROM TableA AS A
WHERE NOT A.FieldB IS NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT A.Category, "FieldC", A.FieldC
FROM TableA AS A
WHERE NOT A.FieldC IS NULL;
```

To export the data into new table, use query:

```
SELECT B.* INTO TableB
FROM (
   --above query
)  AS B;
```

Do not forget to add autonumber field (as primary key) to *TableB* to be able to identify each record.

As per my understanding, you want to pivot data. It's not so simple, becasue we need to simulate

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY FieldName, ORDER BY ID)
```

which is not supported in MS Access. How to workaround it?

```
SELECT B.ID, B.Category, B.FieldName, B.FieldValue,
       (SELECT COUNT(A.FieldName)
        FROM TableB AS A
        WHERE A.FieldName=B.FieldName AND A.ID >=B.ID
        GROUP BY A.FieldName ) AS TRank
FROM TableB AS B;
```

It should produce below record set:

```
ID  Category    FieldName   FieldValue  TRank
1   CAT1        FieldA      A           3
2   CAT1        FieldA      D           2
3   CAT1        FieldA      F           1
4   CAT1        FieldB      B           1
5   CAT1        FieldC      C           2
6   CAT1        FieldC      E           1
```

But... you can't use above query as a source of pivot data, because of "*The Microsoft Access database engine does not recognize  as a valid field name or expression. (Error 3070)*" error message. So, finally, you should export these data into another table (let's say *TableC*).

```
SELECT C.* INSERT INTO TableC
FROM TableB AS C
```

Now, you can pivot data:

```
TRANSFORM First(A.FieldValue) AS FirstOfFieldValue
SELECT A.Category, A.TRank
FROM TableC AS A
GROUP BY A.Category, A.TRank
PIVOT A.FieldName;
```

Result:

```
Category    TRank   FieldA  FieldB  FieldC
CAT1        1       F       B       E
CAT1        2       D       C
CAT1        3       A
```

Cheers,
Maciej

Comment: You're very welcome ;) If my answer was helpfull, please accept it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Take a look at: [Microsoft Access condense multiple lines in a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5174362/microsoft-access-condense-multiple-lines-in-a-table/5174843#5174843)

or get the cloud version here https://www.apponfly.com/en/application/microsoft-access-2013

Works pretty good

Comment: This is the equivelant of the MySQL Group_Concat function, which is close to what I need, but not quite it, since it concatenates all the rows in a group into a single row with delimited data.