# Concatenating values based on 2 adjacent values in MS Access

Tags: ms-access, concatenation

I have an excel sheet with 500,000 rows imported into MS Access. It has 3 columns in the below format

```
 Staff    Locations     Roles
   1      Location1     Role1
   1      Location2     Role1
   2      Location2     Role2
   3      Location3     Role3
   3      Location3     Role4
```

I am trying to get the output in the below format

```
 Staff      Locations                 Roles
   1        Location1, Location2      Role1
   2        Location2                 Role2
   3        Location3                 Role3
   3        Location3                 Role4
```

Any suggestions on how I can accomplish the same in MS Access?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try using the solution posted at [this SO question.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5517233/ms-access-query-concatenating-rows-through-a-query)

Comment: @bill Thanks I have had looked into it. That solution concatenates based on similar values in one column. I am trying to accomplish the same based on similar values in two columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure how the code provided by @Bill works, as I have not used it or tested it, although I have used one that has proven to be a bit more flexible to the needs. The function is written by Allen Browne, called [ConcatRelated](http://allenbrowne.com/func-concat.html).

The function takes in three main arguments, similar to a Domain function.

1. The **Field** you are trying to combine/concatenate, is your first argument.
2. The **Table** you are looking up to, is your second argument.
3. The **Condition** by which it should group by.

There are two other optional arguments, in which you can tell how to **Order** the result (fourth argument) and what **Separator** you want (fifth argument), default is *comma*.

Then the function can be used in a Query, something like.

```
SELECT
    Staff,      
    ConcatRelated("Locations", "yourTableName", "Staff = " & yourTableName.Staff & " AND Roles = '" yourTableName.Roles "'") As NewLocation              
    Roles
FROM
    yourTableName
GROUP BY 
    Staff,
    Roles;
```

That should give you the right information.

Comment: Based on your suggestion I tried the query as below 
SELECT myTable.Staff, ConcatRelated("Locations","myTable","Staff = '" & myTable.Staff & "' AND Roles = '" & myTable.Roles & "'") AS NewLocation, myTable.Roles
FROM myTable;
The query performed the concatenation but I noticed it does not remove the duplicate cell after concatenation. So I am ending up with the same number of rows in the below format
 Staff    Locations                   Roles
   1      Location1, Location2   Role1
   1      Location1, Location2   Role1
   2      Location2                     Role2

Comment: @PottaPitot, you are missing the GROUP BY. I have included that in my answer. Any reason why you have not included that?

Comment: Yup that fixed it. That was my bad for not including it. Thanks a lot for the solution. You saved a huge amount of my time.