# MS Access group by add field together

Tags: group-by, ms-access-2007

I need to combine recorders in a table like the following.

OrderID TrackingID

1     1Z4568266843

1     1Z4568268627

2     1Z9884332583

2     1Z9886827553

2     1Z6358132558

to this

OrderID TrackingID

1     1Z4568266843|1Z4568268627

2     1Z9884332583|1Z9886827553|1Z6358132558

Is there a command I can use in a query to do this?  If not, what other way I can do this?
Thanks for any help.

Comment: You can create custom logic by utilizing VBA to cater your requirement.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ms Access Query: Concatenating Rows through a query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5517233/ms-access-query-concatenating-rows-through-a-query)