# How can I program a field in a query to display a comma separated list of unique values in the subdatasheet for that record?

Tags: mysql, ms-access, ms-access-2016

I am trying to make my query a bit more navigable and give the user a bit more info about the records in the subdatasheet at a glance. I want to create a new field to the right of 'Component' that automatically appends all unique values of the 'Model' field for the records subdatasheet. Exampls below.
Any information helps. Thanks!

[image: It should say 'A, B' in the field next to 'Rotor Blade']

[image: It should say 'A' in the field next to 'Stator Blade']

Answer (score 0):

You're going to need a custom function to handle this in Access. See [Ms Access Query: Concatenating Rows through a query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5517233/ms-access-query-concatenating-rows-through-a-query#5517333). There are a couple of approaches there for implementing a custom function to do the row value concatenation you need.