# How to concatenate result strings in a MS Access Query obtained by GROUP BY

Tags: sql, string, ms-access, concatenation

I have seen that strings can be concatenated in Access with &.

However, I cannot write the following query:

```
SELECT age, &names ==> this line does not work, how can I concatenate the strings? 
    FROM table GROUP BY age;
```

So that I get for example: `"30; JohnWilliamPeter",` all of them 30 years old.

Any way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean:

```
 SELECT age & "; " & names
 FROM table 
 GROUP BY age & "; " & names
```

However, this seems like you are aiming at a solution that should be presentation, not SQL.

Comment: I don't want to concatenate the age and the name, but a list of names. I just found on another thread that there is no way to do that without using a MS function: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5174362/microsoft-access-condense-multiple-lines-in-a-table/5174843#5174843 That's bad!