# How can I get a pivot table with concatenated values?

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007, pivot-table

I have the following data:

```
|   ID     |   TYPE   |  USER_ID |
|----------|----------|----------|
|        1 |        A |        7 |
|        1 |        A |        8 |
|        1 |        B |        6 |
|        2 |        A |        9 |
|        2 |        B |        5 |
```

I'm trying to create a query to return

```
|   ID     |   RESULT |
|----------|----------|
|        1 |  7, 8, 6 |
|        2 |     9, 5 |
```

The USER_ID values must be ordered by the TYPE attribute.

Since I'm using MS ACCESS, I'm trying to pivot. What I've tried:

```
TRANSFORM first(user_id)
SELECT id, type
FROM mytable
GROUP BY id, type
ORDER BY type
PIVOT user_id
```

Error:

> Too many crosstab column headers (4547).

I'm missing something in the syntax. However, it seems to be wrong since the `first()` aggregate needs to be changed to something else to concatenate the results.

PS: I'm using MS-ACCESS 2007. If you know a solution for SQL-Server or Oracle using only SQL (without vendor functions or stored procedures), I'll probably accept your answer since it will help me to find a solution for this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to use **PIVOT**. Pivot will create a **column** named after each of your user IDs (1 - 7). Your **TYPE** field doesn't seem to do anything either.

Unfortunately, doing this in SQL Server requires the use of a [function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194852/concatenate-many-rows-into-a-single-text-string) (**FOR XML Path**) that's not available in **Access**.

Here's a link with a [similar Access function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5174362/microsoft-access-condense-multiple-lines-in-a-table/5174843#5174843) to do something similar.