# MS access avoiding duplicate details

Tags: ms-access

I currently have a report with a group value-indexes and the details of those value-indexes.
ex:

```
a
   Harry 
   Potter               
b                
   Harry                        
   Potter
c
   Ron               
   Wesley
```

a,b,c are value index of a **group** and the names are values from details.
I'm trying to avoid repetition of details-value.
So:

```
a,b               
   Harry             
   Potter
c
   Ron
   Wesley
```

How do I achieve this?
EDIT: I reformatted the example to better understand what's going on

Comment: Your table has columns a, b and c or rows a, b and c?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Microsoft Access condense multiple lines in a table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5174362/microsoft-access-condense-multiple-lines-in-a-table)

Comment: Should note that this is a report, not a table.

Comment: All reports are bound to recordsources either tables or stored queries. Can you post the table structure or query statement?

Comment: I don't see how posting the query would help, I just want 2 groups with identical sub-group values to merge together just like in the example. The example given above is a summed up version of my query.