# Access: query for concatenation of texts of same field

Tags: ms-access, vba

From the table `Table`, I would like to build a query that gives me the table `Query`.

The first issue is to build `Query.Note` as a concatenation of `Table.Note`.

Te second issue, more difficult, is to concatenate `Table.Project + ": " + Table.Note` each time that `Table.Note` is not empty.

Some clues?

For my needs, it is enough to solve the first issue. The second one would be great to have.

I am open to VBA-solutions.

Thanks in advance!

[image][image]

Answer (score 1):

This involves using the "GetList"  Function that is found [Microsoft Access condense multiple lines in a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5174362/microsoft-access-condense-multiple-lines-in-a-table/5174843#5174843).

Please note that Table and Query are reserved words, and that Note needed to be made plural as Notes.

```
SELECT 
  T2.Client
  ,GetList("Select Project & "": "" & Note From myTable as T1 where T1.Client  =  """ &  T2.Client & """","","; ") AS Notes

FROM myTable as T2
GROUP BY T2.Client;
```