# How can I do a SQL inner join where a value in ANY column matches?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have two tables in an Access database. One table is an attendance table and the other is a students table. The attendance table contains dates and student ID's. ID is the primary key in the students table and attendanceDate is the pk in the attendance table. What I want is a query that will return dates and student names so I can display them back to the user. The complication is that the Attendance table contains up to 75 student ID's for each date, so if I do a standard inner join it would have to contain 75 "OR" clauses which is quite cumbersome, and Access will only allow twenty something inner joins anyhow.
Is there a way I can do something like this:

```
SELECT a.attendanceDate FROM (Attendance as a WHERE a.[attendanceDate] BETWEEN #01/01/2020# AND #01/31/2020# INNER JOIN Students AS s ON s.[studentID] = a.[ANY_COLUMN]);
```

In this example it should return attendance records for the month of January 2020 something like this:

01/02/2020 'Mike Johnson'

01/10/2020 'Mike Johnson', 'Mary Smith'

01/25/2020 'Mary Smith', 'Chad Jones', 'Kyrie Erving'

Comment: Attendance has 75 columns for StudentsID? That would be poor data model.

Comment: I agree with ComputerVersteher that your problem is the inappropriate data model. You should change it. Otherwise many of your queries will have to be "cumbersome" (and slow for that matter).

Comment: And as to your results: Is `'Mary Smith', 'Chad Jones', 'Kyrie Erving'` supposed to be one string? As far as I know, MS-Access features no string aggregation, so you will have to do this in your app (VBA-Script?) and only select atomic data instead (`01/25/2020 'Mary Smith'`, `01/25/2020 'Chad Jones'`, `01/25/2020 'Kyrie Erving'`).

Comment: The return values should be in the form of a record set or table

Answer (score -1):

Quickfix: Create a form with Attendance as Recordsource and create a Combobox for each Student column with`Select id, Studentname From Students`as datasource,bound column = 1 and width column1 =0. That will show all students, one column each.

If you want to have the students as one separated string, replace id with name and concat all columns to one:

```sql
SELECT
    attendanceDate,
    Dlookup("Studentname","Students","id = " & StudentID1) & "," &
    Dlookup("Studentname","Students","id = " & StudentID2 ) & "," &
    ... 
    Dlookup("Studentname","Students","id = " & StudentID75 ) AS AllStudents
FROM
    Attendance
```

But fix your data model ASAP!

As @Thorsten Kettner noted: two fields, one for date, one for studentid. PK is now the combination of date and id.

You can combine the rows with same date by using [GetList](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5174843/9439330) in a query.