# Concatenate duplicates in one row

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I have a table that has the following fields(columns)

```
First Name   |  Last Name | Email | ContactID | AccountID
```

I have duplicate rows with the same names, emails and AccountID but different ContactIDs. 
Is there a way I can build a query that can return back a list of ContactID appended to each other that match to one Account?

Lets say I have

```
First Name   |  Last Name | Email | ContactID | AccountID
----------------------------------------------------------
fname        |  lanem     | e@m.ca| 123       | 1
fname        |  lanem     | e@m.ca| 124       | 1
```

returns

```
ContactID | AccountID
----------------------
123 , 124 | 1
```

I'm using access (not by choice)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Combine rows in Access 2007](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/92698/combine-rows-in-access-2007)

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1920552/concatenate-rows-into-1-access-2007/1921002#1921002 and http://allenbrowne.com/func-concat.html. Note that User defined functions cannot be used outside of MS Access.

Comment: @Remou the duplicate questions you added combines all the rows together, my question was asking to combine duplicates that are found based on one column entry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can paste the following code into a "regular" VBA Module (not a Class Module associated with a Form), edit the table name as required, and then use the function as a column in a query like this: `listContactIDs([AccountID])`

```
Public Function listContactIDs(AccountID As Long) As String
Dim cdb As DAO.Database, rst As DAO.Recordset, s As String
Dim Separator As String

Separator = ", "

Set cdb = CurrentDb
Set rst = cdb.OpenRecordset( _
        "SELECT ContactID FROM [TableName] WHERE AccountID=" & _
            AccountID & " ORDER BY ContactID", _
        dbOpenSnapshot)
s = ""
Do While Not rst.EOF
    s = s & rst!ContactID & Separator
    rst.MoveNext
Loop
rst.Close
Set rst = Nothing
Set cdb = Nothing
If Len(s) > 0 Then
    ' remove trailing separator
    s = Left(s, Len(s) - Len(Separator))
End If
listContactIDs = s
End Function
```

Comment: When I tried to put listContactIDs([AccountID]) in the query it said lisContactIDs is not defined

Comment: double-check your spelling: "lisContactIDs" <> "listContactIDs"

Comment: Sorry, about that that was a mistake in the comment not in my code.

Comment: Did you paste the function into a "regular" VBA module (not a class module associated with a Form)?