# MS Access: Filling data cell with data from multiple rows in another table

Tags: sql, ms-access

I need to fill MS access database table with a number of information about certain products. I managed to fill almost everything, but I ran into following issue:

I have a separate record for each part of the same product in a table called *Parts*. I also have a separate record for each product in a table called *Products*.

I need to take data from *Parts.PartCode* to *Products.ListOfParts* if the *Parts.ProductCode* and *Products.ProductCode* is the same, however I have two problems:

1. I do not know how to make a query that will fill particular row in *Products.ListOfParts* with data from numerous rows in *Parts.PartCode* (could be anything between 1 and 10);
2. For some reason, even though the table *Products* is filled completely, except for the *Products.ListOfParts* column, every time I try to make an `INSERT` query, it asks me to provide value of *Products.ProductCode*. This is the query I tried running:

   ```
   INSERT INTO Products ( ListOfParts )
   SELECT Parts.PartCode
   FROM Parts
   WHERE Parts.ProductCode = Products.ProductCode;
   ```

Edit (sample data from tables):

Products:

```
+----+---------+-------+-------------+-------------+
| Id |  Name   | SpId  | ListOfParts | ProductCode |
+----+---------+-------+-------------+-------------+
|  1 | HWN2007 | Y2271 |             | OP00P0      |
|  2 | SD39HE  | 6G121 |             | NE0301      |
+----+---------+-------+-------------+-------------+
```

Parts:

```
+-------+---------+-------------+-----------+
|  Id   |  SpId   | ProductCode | PartCode  |
+-------+---------+-------------+-----------+
| 15321 | 5162F7  | OP00P0      | VC-192919 |
| 15322 | 5172H1  | OP00P0      | VC-888192 |
+-------+---------+-------------+-----------+
```

Desired result:

```
+----+---------+-------+----------------------+-------------+
| Id |  Name   | SpId  |     ListOfParts      | ProductCode |
+----+---------+-------+----------------------+-------------+
|  1 | HWN2007 | Y2271 | VC-192919, VC-888192 | OP00P0      |
+----+---------+-------+----------------------+-------------+
```

Comment: An example of the contents & structure of your `Parts` table and `Products` table, and the desired result would be helpful here. From your description it sounds like an `UPDATE` query may be more suitable.

Comment: Apologies, should've thought about that earlier.

Comment: Your sample tables are almost unreadable. See [how to share a table for MS Access questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359195/7296893)

Comment: Fixed, sorry again!

Comment: There are many, many answers describing how to concatenate related fields. The oldest I could find is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1920552/7296893). However, a good alternate resource is [Allen Browne's ConcatRelated](http://allenbrowne.com/func-concat.html).

Comment: Why do you want comma-separated values in one column? In almost every case except presentation, it is never a good idea. This becomes very difficult and inefficient to query such parts and breaks the normalization rule of relational databases. Simply use one-to-many relationship between *Products* and *Parts*.

Comment: I do not mind if they are comma-separated or not, all I need is the PartCode from all the parts with matching ProductCode to be included in ListOfParts of the Product with matching ProductCode - I take it that one-to-many relationship is the solution here?